# Unable to display Image on change of field value vf page

Tags: visualforce

I am trying to display image dynamically on change of `<apex:inputText/>`field value. But image is not dynamically displayed. Is there anything i am missing.

```
                <div class="panel panel-info">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" style="width: 53%;">

                            <li class="active">

                                <apex:image id="image1" style="height:19px;width:19px;margin-left: 29px;" url="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/social-messaging-ui-color-shapes/128/alert-triangle-red-512.png" rendered="{!acc.AnnualRevenue ==null}"/>
                                <apex:image id="image2" style="height:19px;width:19px;margin-left: 29px;" url="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/toolbar-signs-2/512/apply_ok_check_yes_dialog-512.png" rendered="{!acc.AnnualRevenue !=null}"/>
                                <a data-target="#home" data-toggle="tab">AUM/Tax</a></li>
                            <li>

                                <a data-target="#profile" data-toggle="tab">Sub Accounts</a></li>
                        </ul>

                        <div class="tab-content">
                            <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <br/>
                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="aName" class="label">Total</label> &nbsp;
                                            <apex:inputText value="{!acc.AnnualRevenue}" style="width:auto;">
                                                 <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="image1,image2"/>
                                            </apex:inputText>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:

```
1. Check for AnnualRevenue = 0 or AnnualRevenue != 0 while rendering images.
2. Keep the entire div under a <apex:ouputPanel" and reRender the panel in actionSupport.
```

Let me know for any further questions. Thank you.

```
<apex:outputPanel Id="thepanel">

        <div class="panel panel-info">
                <div class="panel-body" id="renderTag">
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" style="width: 53%;">

                        <li class="active">

                            <apex:image id="image1" style="height:19px;width:19px;margin-left: 29px;" url="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/social-messaging-ui-color-shapes/128/alert-triangle-red-512.png" rendered="{!acc.AnnualRevenue ==0}"/>
                            <apex:image id="image2" style="height:19px;width:19px;margin-left: 29px;" url="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/toolbar-signs-2/512/apply_ok_check_yes_dialog-512.png" rendered="{!acc.AnnualRevenue !=0}"/>
                            <a data-target="#home" data-toggle="tab">AUM/Tax</a></li>
                        <li>

                            <a data-target="#profile" data-toggle="tab">Sub Accounts</a></li>
                    </ul>

                    <div class="tab-content">
                        <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">
                            <div class="row">
                                <br/>
                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="aName" class="label">Total</label> &nbsp;
                                        <apex:inputText value="{!acc.AnnualRevenue}" style="width:auto;">
                                             <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="thepanel"/>
                                        </apex:inputText>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

</apex:outputPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

- When page loads one of the image will not be available depending on AccountRevenue value on page. So
  you can't get either image1 or image2 htmlSection to rerender.
- So you need to add a panel to both images and rerender that panel from
  actionSupport.

...

```
    <apex:form>
        <apex:outputPanel id="outputPanel">
            revenue is : {!acc.AnnualRevenue}
<apex:image id="image1" style="height:19px;width:19px;margin-left: 29px;" url="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/social-messaging-ui-color-shapes/128/alert-triangle-red-512.png" rendered="{!acc.AnnualRevenue ==null}"/>
<apex:image id="image2" style="height:19px;width:19px;margin-left: 29px;" url="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/toolbar-signs-2/512/apply_ok_check_yes_dialog-512.png" rendered="{!acc.AnnualRevenue !=null}"/>
            </apex:outputPanel>

<apex:inputText value="{!acc.AnnualRevenue}" style="width:auto;">
<apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="outputPanel"/>
</apex:inputText>    

        </apex:form>
```